# Reset password after first successful login in Django python

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am building an web application using existing Auth features in Django where admin create user profile with username and password. Admin created user name and password will be given to user to login. So for security reasons I need to ask user to reset password (given by admin) after user's first successful login. To reset password, I will be displaying template where user should be entering only new password and new password again for confirmation. This new password will be updated in sqlite database.

So whenever admin changes the users password. I need to ask users to reset password after first successful login.

I know this if off topic for stacoverflow and for reasons I couldnt post a question in StackExchange. Please refer me or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean attribute in the User model which gets set True, whenever Admin user sets the password for that user.

Then in middleware, you can check if that User needs to set the password, then correspondingly you can redirect the user to Reset password view.

You can use these [blogs](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html) to create a password reset views. Middleware logic you need to write by yourself, for setting that attribute you can override User save in admin.py, set that attribute and call super

Comment: Hi Rahul, I am new to Django. Above given blog link talks about reset password trough mail. But I need to reset password right after first login. That means, after first successful login after password reset, display page where user enters new password twice and then redirect the user to login page again, so that user logs in with new password. It would be great help if you can point me some code or blog for this. Thanks Rahul

Comment: that part of code you have to write . by yourself, its like normally creating an API

Comment: see this one it will help you 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change